# using =IF equations over multiple columns

Tags: excel

I have the numbers in Column `W >4800` displaying `">4800"` in Column X, and the numbers below 0 in Column W showing 0 in Column X using

```
=IF(W222>4800,">4800",MAX(W222,0))
```

what I need now is that if a number in Column V is >0 I need the cell in Column X to show `"+IVE"` but still have the same responses to the =IF calculation above.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 concepts here,

1. you can use the `AND` function within your `IF` function to determine things like `IF(AND(W222>4800,V222>0)...` (if (W222 > 4800) AND (V222 > 0)...)
2. you can use nested `IF` statements to cover all the conditions you're looking for

I think something like the following should work

```
=IF(AND(W222>4800,V222>0),">4800+IVE",IF(W222>4800,">4800",IF(V222>0,MAX(W222,0)&"+IVE",MAX(W222,0))))
```